# Migrating from Provider to Riverpod

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod

I am stuck using Provider and came across Riverpod which is just the next gen of Provider. I am trying to create a StreamProvider using Riverpod but I am getting an error.

Here is the code for creating the StreamProvider:

```
final trxnStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<Trxns>>((ref) {
  final stream = firestoreService.getAgencyTrxns();
  return stream.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Trxns.fromFirestore(doc.data)).toList());
});
```

The error I get marks the code "doc.data". Here is the error text:

```
The argument type 'Object? Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

Here is the code for "Trxns.fromFirestore(doc.data)":

```
Trxns.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : clientFName = firestore['clientFName'],
        clientLName = firestore['clientLName'];
```

I'm still new to this and am having a hard time understanding the error message. Is it saying that "doc.data" is not the right type? If so, how do I fix this? If not, what is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, dynamic> data() => dartify(jsObject.data());
```

data is a method so you need to call it:

```
doc.data()
```

doc.data mean you want to pass a function